# Linear Equation Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is the question:

If the linear equation
$y'+p(x)y=q(x)$
has solutions $y=1$ and $y=x$, what are $p$ and $q$?

Am I just supposed to substitute y=1 and y=x into the equation?  What I mean is if I plug in y=1, I get 0+p(x)=0.  That doesn't seem right to me, but I'm not sure how to go about this problem if that's not correct.  If it is correct, do I do the same thing to y=x?  Thanks.

Comment: You are just supposed to substitute these solutions into the equation, but letting $y=1$ will give $p(x)=q(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $y=1$ you get
$$
0+p\left(x\right)=q\left(x\right)
$$
and from $y=x$ you get
$$
1+p\left(x\right)x=q\left(x\right).
$$
Combining the two you get
$$
p\left(x\right)=q\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{1-x}.
$$

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Thanks a lot!